# How to create java class from wsdl(soap-1.2) file with java-jdk-1.5

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I tried,

```
java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java -o src file.xml
```

That file.xml uses soap-1.2 but i have java-1.5 with axis.jar.

I got this error:

```
java.io.IOException: ERROR: Missing <soap:fault> element inFault ..
```

How can i solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `-o` is meant for output and is usually used this way

```
java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java -o destination_folder input.wsdl
```

A `java.io.IOException` looks like the `file.xml` is not correct. Could you please post it as well?

Comment: I tried that: java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java -o dest file.wsdl, still same error

Comment: Part of that file:       <wsdl:fault name="XXFaultException">
        <soap12:fault name="XXFaultException" use="literal"></soap12:fault>
      </wsdl:fault>